# Backbone.js Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: jquery, wordpress, backbone.js, underscore.js

Im new to backbone, trying to fetch json from the Wordpress json plugin and render into a template, but when looping through posts I get the following error **Uncaught ReferenceError: posts is not defined** Any help appreciated. Thanks...

```
   jQuery(function($) {
    var Post = Backbone.Model.extend();
    var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Post,
        url: '/api/get_post/?json=get_recent_posts',
        parse: function(resp) {
            console.log("posts", resp);
            return resp;
        }
    });
    var listView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#content',
        template: _.template($("#post-template").html()),
        initialize: function() {
            this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        },
        render: function() {
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "!/archive": "archive"
        },
        archive: function() {
            this.postList = new Posts();
            this.postListView = new listView({
                model: this.postList
            });
            this.postList.fetch();
            this.postListView.render();
        }
    });
    var app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Template

```
<script id="post-template" type="text/template">
    <ul>
      <% _.each(posts, function(post) { %>
        <li id="<%= post.id %>">
          <a href="<%= post.url %>"><%= post.thumbnail %></a>
        </li>
      <% }); %>
    </ul>
</script>
```

Json

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 1,
    "count_total": 1,
    "pages": 1,
    "posts": [{
        "id": 4,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "test-post",
        "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8888\/2013\/04\/test-post\/",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "Test Post",
        "title_plain": "Test Post",
        "content": "",
        "excerpt": "",
        "date": "2013-04-17 15:12:21",
        "modified": "2013-04-19 14:13:00",
        "categories": [],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "admin",
            "name": "admin",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "nickname": "admin",
            "url": "",
            "description": ""
        },
        "comments": [],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "closed",
        "thumbnail": "http:\/\/localhost:8888\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/04\/test-image-150x150.jpg"
    }]
}
```

Comment: That error is coming from the template compiler. As a hint, do a `console.log(this.model.toJSON())` in your `render()` and see what prints out. Also, `this.postList` is a collection, so why are you passing it in as a `model`?

Comment: @Bojangles about the last part, there is no `collection` key for views in Backbone, so if you want to create a "collection view", you still have to use the `model` key. That's not much of a problem.

Comment: @Loamhoof Please read [the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) before you comment. From the Backbone docs: `There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: model, collection, el, id, className, tagName and attributes.`

Comment: @Bojangles oh, seemed to have missed the collection one. But still, it doesn't seem to change anything, I don't recall having seen any use of it in the code.

Comment: It doesn't really AFAIK, however it _does_ make the code much more understandable and semantically correct

Comment: Agreed, it's very hard to understand the code when you're treating the collection as a model. At first glance, it also appears to be the root cause of the error; you're using an Array as an Object and calling toJSON() on the array, then trying to get an object key (as @Loamhoof has answered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Collection#toJSON` will return **an array**. Therefore there is no `posts` key. Try using `$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()[0]));` as you only have one model in your collection (which is weird).

You may want to parse your response in the `parse` methods to return `resp.posts` so your collection has more meaning and actually creates one `Post` model per post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like:

```
$(this.el).html({
   posts : this.template(this.model.toJSON())
});
```

instead of:

```
$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

Comment: Simply no, that won't give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `posts` as the variable that contains the collection/array in your underscore template, you need to pass it as a property to the template function:

```
$(this.el).html(this.template({ posts: this.model.toJSON() } ));
```

I would have also thought your `Posts` Collection class should have returned the posts in the   `parse` function as shown below (as the posts are a property of the JSON that's being returned):

```
var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Post,
    url: '/api/get_post/?json=get_recent_posts',
    parse: function(resp) {
        console.log("posts", resp);
        return resp.posts || [];  // grab the posts from the JSON 
    }
});
```

And, often by convention you might want to switch to using the `collection` attribute of the View:

```
this.postListView = new listView({
     collection: this.postList
});
```

And then change your template call: `{ posts: this.collection.toJSON() }`.