# jQuery JsonP renders error Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery19107590448246337473_1375193471216 is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm not sure what to make of this error, every request has a unique string. The jsonP i'm requesting is a jsonP proxy that, as far as I can tell, is configured as it should.

```
var url = 'https://phpproxy-dev.herokuapp.com/?url=http://personer.eniro.se/resultat/'+who+'/'+where+'&callback=?';
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            //console.log(data)
        });
```

response:

```
jQuery19107590448246337473_1375193471216({"status":{"http_code":200},"contents":"//an html page wrapped in a json-object, I can't post it because it hangs chrome when I try to push the code button i stackoverflow. "})
```

I Run the code in greasemonkey on a https-page.

Comment: @Spokey It's what jQuery generates for JSONP. As you can see, the OP **isn't** using that. But they're using `$.getJSON` and providing the `callback=?` in the URL

Comment: Could you show how you are requesting this endpoint in your javascript code?

Comment: @neal error Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery19107590448246337473_1375193471216 is not defined

Comment: @Neal: The error is in the title

Comment: @Neal I think this code is at the end of some block, that's why I indented the `var url = ...` line. The `}` at the end of the code made me think that

Comment: @DarinDimitrov what does that mean?

Comment: Since jQuery will create a function with the correct callback name, I could only imagine that you change the callback name in your server script somehow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148723/backbone-js-uncaught-referenceerror

Comment: Your code works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/GPD7r/. (Using jQuery 1.9.1, which seems to be the same as yours).

Comment: @Matt That's weird, I run it using gresemonkey,(tampermonkey, for chrome), that might have something to do with it

Comment: If you are using greasemonkey why don't you just request the page directly

Comment: @Esailija It's part of a script that makes multiple requsts, also, greasmonkey apparently doesn't run across multiple websites

Comment: Do you really need jQuery for this? the jsonp request itself is easy enough to do without jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/n3p9B/

Comment: @KevinB Well, no But I get the same error nevertheless: Uncaught ReferenceError: myjsonpcallback is not defined ?url=http://personer.eniro.se/resultat/%20Khalidah%20Medhat%2019690605-1229/%20281%2040%20H%C3%84SSLEHOLM&callback=myjsonpcallback:1
(anonymous function)

Comment: In that case, you need to figure out exactly what is being considered the global scope in your context. That's where the callback needs to be defined. you probably won't be able to use jQuery to make this ajax request if the global context isn't the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apperently, Greasemonkey doesn't support jsonP. I had much more success with GM_xmlhttpRequest that disables the xhr-block.

Answer (score 3):

JSONP call in jQuery works the following way:

jQuery defines the callback function in the **global scope** (with unique name like `jQuery19107590448246337473_1375193471216`).

Then it adds the script to the document, which is expected to return the code which looks like

```
jQuery19107590448246337473_1375193471216(<some JSON data here>);
```

The problem with Greasemonkey is that your code works in the sandbox, and those **global scope** is in fact the sandbox's global scope, not the actual window scope (unsafeWindow). And this sandbox is normally not accessible from the outside.
As the result, the requested script fails to call this callback function `jQuery19107590448246337473_1375193471216`.

However the good thing here is that you just don't need JSONP call here at all.
 JSONP is developed as a workaround for cross-origin restriction. But GreaseMonkey provides you with nice GM_xmlhttpRequest function, which doesn't have such restrictions.
 So you can directly send GET requests from your script to other domains, without using JSONP wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `$.ajax` and passing the args you need:

```
var who = "john";
var where = "london";

$.ajax({
    url:'https://phpproxy-dev.herokuapp.com/',
    data: {
        'url':'http://personer.eniro.se/resultat/'+who+'/'+where
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(textStatus + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); //data.contents has the HTML
    }   
});
```

See Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/mZG83/ (I'm outputting the HTML on the textarea in this example).

Comment: new error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : phpproxy-dev.herokuapp.com/:1
parsererrorError: jQuery19107590448246337473_1375193471216 was not called

Comment: did you see that I was running greasemonkey, it initiates jquery, where those numbers come from but maybe it's associated?

Comment: The error indicates that said function isn't defined on the window, where `window` is whatever jQuery is using as the window. specifying a specific callback shouldn't change the error (other than what is reported as the callback) since the error is coming from the same place.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren Check the fiddle, I've updated it after I had posted. Now it's okay. And about the numbers I've seend they don't come from the JSON, they are jQuery specifics so the numbers might have timestamp.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery19109166778242215514_1375195463773 is not defined ?callback=jQuery19109166778242215514_1375195463773&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpersoner.eniro.se%2Fresultat%2Fjohn%2Flondon&_=1375195463794:1
(anonymous function) ?callback=jQuery19109166778242215514_1375195463773&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpersoner.eniro.se%2Fresultat%2Fjohn%2Flondon&_=1375195463794:1
parsererrorError: jQuery19109166778242215514_1375195463773 was not called

Comment: @KristofferNolgren What jQuery version you using? I'm using 1.9.1 on my fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/mZG83/

Comment: I'm using 1.9.1, in greasmonkey it's loaded like this:// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js

Comment: @KristofferNolgren Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/859092/684932 You might need to remove and re-install your gm script if you changed the `@require` after installed. Other than that, add `var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;` beofre the script (when a page already have jquery, to not have conflict. more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4261831/684932 )

Comment: Whoever gave -1, please say why, because the fiddle works. OP just added the greasemonkey info later.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL Jquery is woking properly and the site doesn't run another instance of it. (btw, I didn't downvote your answer, I find it excelent!)